# Really binding an argument to a parameter? (Perl6)

Tags: variable-assignment, raku, variable-binding

The [Perl6 docs](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature) state "By default, parameters are bound to their argument and marked as read-only." But running the following code:

```
# Example 1
sub f1 ( $x ) { say $x.VAR.WHAT; say $x.WHAT; say $x }
f1(1);
```

yields:

```
(Scalar)
(Int)
1
```

while this code:

```
# Example 2
my $y := 1;
say $y.VAR.WHAT; say $y.WHAT; say $y;
```

yields:

```
(Int)
(Int)
1
```

It's the `(Scalar)` in the output of Example1 that I do not understand: why is there a Scalar when I supposedly bind the Int 1 - argument to the identifier `$x` ? It seems as if the value `1` got "assigned" to `$x`, rather than "bound".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Scalar` containers are also used to indicate items, and thus prevent flattening of them. In the absence of a type constraint, the implementation will conservatively wrap the incoming argument into a read-only `Scalar` container to avoid any unexpected flattening taking place. Contrast this:

```
sub foo($x) {
    my @a = $x;
    say @a.elems;
}
foo([1,2,3]);
```

Which outputs 1 (no flattening), with a sigilless binding:

```
sub foo(\x) {
    my @a = x;
    say @a.elems;
}
foo([1,2,3])
```

Which outputs 3, since no item context is imposed. Were the `Scalar` container not there, both would output 3.

In the presence of a non-`Iterable` type constraint, this wrapping will be omitted. Thus writing:

```
sub f1(Int $x) {
    say $x.VAR.WHAT;
    say $x.WHAT;
    say $x
}
f1(1)
```

Will output:

```
(Int)
(Int)
1
```

With `.VAR` simply yielding identity on a non-container.